# Strike me down, and I shall become more powerful

Tags: riddle, word, computer-puzzle

By hitting me, you make everyone understand why you have attacked all before me, as well as why you will hit all others that come after me.

Comment: @Downvoters - Reason for downvotes so I can do a better job next time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer:

> The space bar. Each time you hit it, it ends the previous word and makes it and the next word that will be typed more readable.

Answer (score 4):

My guess:

> Enter key (or submit button) or possibly Period key - Submitting your text explains why you struck keys earlier as well as providing context for your next submission

Comment: close.  I was thinking of something more that makestextreadable.

Comment: I'mafraidIdon'tunderstandthatlastword.Igiveup.